# Ошибка нахождения адреса записи и адреса элемента записи

Tags: pascal

Есть программа, состоящая из записи из трех целых переменных. Нужно ввести с клавиатуры элементы записи и вывести на монитор адрес второго элемента и адрес записи. tp ругается на **[[[@s](/users/49/sigourney-weaver)](/users/49/sigourney-weaver)](/users/49/sigourney-weaver).c** в коде ниже. Пишет:

> Cannot Read of Write variables of this type

В чем ошибка?

```
TYPE structure = record
   a : integer;
   b : integer;
   c : integer;
end;

var S : structure;

begin
with S do begin
   writeln;
   write('Введите элемент записи a: ');
   read(a);
   write('Введите элемент записи b: ');
   read(b);
   write('Введите элемент записи c: ');
   read(c);
end;

   writeln;
   write('Запись S состоит из: ');
   writeln; write('a = ', s.a);
   writeln; write('b = ', s.b);
   writeln; write('c = ', s.c);

   writeln; write('Адрес второго элемента записи: ', @s.c);
   writeln; write('Адрес записи: ', @s);

end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В паскале есть более родной метод взятия адреса сущности (переменной, функции) - это функция addr.

```
writeln; write('Адрес второго элемента записи: ', ofs(s.c));
writeln; write('Адрес записи: ', ofs(s));
```

upd. нужно просто правильно попросить:)
А можно ещё и так `word(@s.c)`
но если компилятор 16 битный, то там нужно будет ещё правильно адрес выделить

Comment: Этот вариант тоже не работает.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше сделать приведение типов к longint:

```
   writeln; write('Адрес второго элемента записи: ', longint(@s.c));
   writeln; write('Адрес записи: ', longint(@s));
```